# How would society change if all limitations on contracts were removed?

Tags: society, law

All modern legal systems impose limitations on what kind of contracts people can enter into. For example, if two people sign a contract saying that one of them becomes the other's slave for life, that contract is void, even if both of them swear that they signed out of free will. Similarly, if a loan agreement states that in case of a default, the bank may kill the debtor and sell their organs to cover the debt, nothing of that sort can legally happen.

What if legislatures suddenly decided to remove all restrictions on making contracts? What if sane adults could legally consent to any arrangement whatsoever, and be held to it with the force of law afterwards?

It seems clear that this would give rise to extreme forms of (now "legal") exploitation where the weakness of a contractual party is abused, but are there any other less obvious potential effects?

Comment: Millions of people would end up in slavery after clicking "I accept" out of habit when faced with some new EULA for an app.

Comment: I doubt it. No one would just click through an EULA if that were a possible consequence.

Comment: Nobody would sign anything at all, unless the contract started with "this agreement is superseded by existing laws (excluding that crazy change to contract law) and is null and void if it conflicts in any way with pre-existing laws.

Comment: That doesn't seem very likely either, as people already regularly sign contracts of adhesion that put them at a very great disadvantage compared to the party that drafted the contract.

Comment: Why do you assume society would change? Consider that if one company offers a service with a potential consequence of slavery, and another offers the same service at a higher price, but without the slavery option, the latter company will probably get more business. People have a tendency to like freedom.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based. Which should be pretty obvious from the way I structured my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The contract system of law is interesting because of how quickly it degenerates.  Within a few months, the entire system would fall apart enough to demonstrate the key part of the law: "to the full force of the law."

A contract does not make truth.  A contract makes a slip of paper which some people will act upon and call their actions "justified."  Those enforcing said actions would be the arm of the law.  This path typically bifurcates as the contracts being upheld are considered more and more absurd.  Either the long arm of the law demonstrates its humanity, refusing to continue enforcing horrid contracts, or the long arm of the law becomes stone cold, with no compassion in their eyes.

As long as the law is being upheld, we have to ask "what is the law anyway?"  It is generally accepted by linguists that a string of characters has no semantic meaning.  It is only when those symbols are interpreted do those symbols begin to symbolize something which the law can act upon.  Many of us choose to pretend those words have one and only one meaning, but it turns out that linguistically it's more complicated than that.  Words are universally defined with respect to other words, bringing some relativity into everything.

There would almost certainly be a formalized language whose intent was to define every word absolutely (and thus, by definition will fail... but they'll try anyways).  We see it already with concepts like "null and void."  The exact formal meaning could be obscured by such legal texts, permitting predatory acts where one signatory simply isn't aware of a loophole written into the contract.

Beyond that, what is to prevent, say HDE 226868 and Monica Cellio from signing a contract that puts you into slavery, owned by them?  Maintaining the WorldBuilding stack exchange is a lot of work, and I know their job would be easier with a few slave laborers to help!  They sign a contract with each other, and *bam* you're in slavery, because a contract got signed, right?

Well, I'm sure the answer is "wrong" because they didn't have the right to sign away your rights.  But now we have to play games with ownership, and rights.  You have to start defining things like personhood far more strictly.  The careful limitations you must put on these pieces of paper with signatures at the bottom start to pile up.

Pretty soon, you find you have exactly the system we have, with all sorts of limits on what sort of contracts are valid.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition**:

- An *imperative* is something a subject is supposed to do.
- An imperative is *violated* if its subject doesn't do what it's supposed to do
- It is decideable whether any single imperative is violated
- A *contract* between subject A and subject B contains one or more imperatives with respect to subject A or B
- *Laws* are imperatives with respect to all subjects
- A law or contract is *violated* if any of its imperatives is violated by a subject
- A contradiction (of a system of law) in this context means that no matter what a subject does, it is violating the law

### Literal interpretation:

**Assumption**:

- There is a law which contains the imperative that subjects are supposed not to violate their contracts
- There exists at least one other law (exercise to the reader: what if there is no other law?)

Then you can construct a trivial **contradiction** by having party A and party B sign a contract containing the following imperative

> Party A and B are supposed to violate the law.

because if they aren't violating the contract, they are violating the law and if they are violating the contract then they are violating the specific law I assumed.

### Far fetched interpretation

Redefining violation of law:

**Definition**:

- A law is *violated* if any of its imperatives is violated by a subject, unless that subject does so only to avoid violating a contract

**Assumption**:

- There is a law which contains the imperative that subjects are supposed not to violate their contracts

If there is a law, you sign a contract with someone about violating it. This is anarchy. Too lazy to make my mind up about whether it's possible to get a contradiction in this system.

### Conclusion

I also tried some other assumptions, for example:

Using the initial definition of a violation of law again.

**Assumption**:

- There is a law which contains the imperative that subjects are supposed not to violate their contracts
- All laws are of the form "You may not do action a unless Party P which is the victim of a gives you permission"

But this can be deconstructed fairly easily too plus it's too much of a restriction on what laws can be for a state to work (plus doesn't really work in a strict logical sense without some more definitions).

But really the only way you get something other than outright anarchy is to restrict what you can do with a contract. It's really pretty clear from the beginning when you look at how similar contract and law is in the definition. You need a law like "Any imperative in a contract which is violated unless its subject violates the law can't be violated (or makes the entire contract impossible to violate)".
And then you get a society which depends entirely on what kinds of laws you have, as always. That way you can introduce consumer protection laws to any degree. You need to make your mind up about how much consumer protection you want, exactly, and then it becomes possible to guess what the society would look like.